# Angular's ng include directive not working for the expected link

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

Let's say I have a link

```
<a href="#one">Take me to one</a>
```

and an article:

```
<article id="one"><h2>This is one</h2></article>
```

The link takes me to the article. But after moving those 2 lines in a separate sep.html file and including sep.html in my main page (index.html) like this:

```
<div ng-include="'sep.html'"></div>
```

the link doesn't work anymore. And instead of showing **.../index.html#one**, the address bar shows **.../index.html#/one**. Manually removing the extra "/" in the address bar takes me to the right place. Why is that and how can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular listens for hashchange event and prevents default browser jump-to-id behaviour. The simple way to tell Angular not to do so for your anchor links is to use `target="_self"` attribute:

```
<a href="#one" target="_self">Take me to one</a>
```